# Getting the size of an URL with referenced content

Tags: monitoring, size

Is there a recommendable way to get the bytes size of an URL with all referenced images, CSS and javascript files (the number of bytes a normal visitor has to receive before the page has fully loaded in the browser) by means of command line utilities? Something like (fictious):

```
wget --output-format=mozilla-archive-format --with-referenced-content --compression=0       \
    'http://www.example.com/' > temp.maff && stat -c%s temp.mapp ; rm temp.maff
```

I would aggree to limitations like, not including references that are dynamically generated and loaded by scripts, …. Just the basic information, getting 4,000,000 when there is a 15,000 bytes HTML page with a 3,985,000 bytes image in it, would be already worth looking at. I currently have a Perl script doing the very basic:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use URI;
$html = `wget -qO - '$ARGV[0]'`;
$sum = length($html);
while($html =~ /\bsrc="(.*?)"/g){
    $url = URI->new_abs($1, $ARGV[0]);
    $head = `curl -I --silent '$url'`;
    if($head =~ /Content-Length: ?(\d+)/){
        $size = scalar($1);
    }else{
        $size = length(`wget -qO - '$url'`);
    }
    $sum += $size;
}
print "$sum\n";
```

However, this has many drawbacks. Only one level of links being followed, no script evaluation, …. Any better approach, maybe a one-liner using mature tools, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant `wget` option is [`-p`/`--page-requisites`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html#index-page-requisites):

> This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to properly display a given HTML page. This includes such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

`-H`/`--span-hosts` is also recommended if the page uses anything from another site (gravatar, google APIs).

`-O`/`--output-document` will output it all to a single file, without any markup or structure.  This is not very helpful most of the time, but good enough if you only need to know its size.

```
wget -p -H 'http://www.example.com/' -O tempfile
wc -c < tempfile
```